# I can’t fix my normal map. I will be really greatful if someone explains me what`s wrong with it

Tags: texturing, uv, normals, baking, normal-map

I tried to bake normals from high poly to low poly and it has no resault, only broken normal map.
I watched so many videos about, did the same or tried change Max Ray Distanse/Extrusion and still have troubles.
I added screenshots with high poly, low poly(with normal map) and baking settings

High poly:
[image]

Low poly:
[image]

Settings:
[image]

Normal map:
[image]

Link for .blend file:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/rruk0aqj7wdgkek/test.blend?dl=0

Comment: Why do you want to bake normals for this model? What problem are you trying to solve with this in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no detail that would require baking normals on the model in your images. Smoothness of the surface can be handled by regular normals. You could use Weighted Normal modifier to have more appropriate shading with low poly bevels, but there is really nothing to bake here.